# Importing updated package in python

Tags: python, scipy, conda

I've updated scipy package in my environment from the terminal and started the Jupiter notebook.
In a cell I run

```
scipy.__version__
```

but that shows the previous version which doesn't have some properties I need. What can be the cause of the problem? 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKboI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be several versions of the package still installed on your machine.
Restart completely the Jupiter notebook (even your computer). Make sure the jupyter notebook is runned in the correct environment where you have updated the package if you are using for example anaconda.
Search for the package name a list all the folders in which is it present.

Comment: Restarting kernel or computer didn't help. Strangely notebook is using the package from the base environment not the one active right now. I've updated scipy in the the base environment and works fine now. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help! Could you validate my answer as the answer to your question then. Thanks!